# Two (seemingly) identical queries, one is faster, why?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, benchmarking

Two seemingly identical queries (as far as a newbie like me can tell, but the first is faster overall in the partial template rendering time (nothing else changed but the ids statement). Also, when testing through rails console, the latter will visibly run a query, the former will not. I do not understand why - and why the first statement is a few *ms* faster than the second - though I can guess it is due to the shorter method chaining to get the same result.

UPDATE: My bad. They are not running the same query, but it still is interesting how a select on all columns is faster than a select on one column. Maybe it is a negligible difference compared to the method chaining though.

```
ids = current_user.activities.map(&:person_id).reverse
SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."user_id" = 1
SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" IN (1, 4, 12, 15, 3, 14, 17, 10, 5, 6) Rendered activities/_activities.html.haml (7.4ms)


ids = current_user.activities.order('id DESC').select{person_id}.map(&:person_id)
SELECT "activities"."person_id" FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY id DESC    
SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" IN (1, 4, 12, 15, 3, 14, 17, 10, 5, 6) Rendered activities/_activities.html.haml (10.3ms)
```

The purpose of the statement is to retrieve the foreign key reference to people in the order in which they appeared in the activities table, (on its PK).
Note: I use [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) for SQL.

Comment: What is `select{person_id}` meant to do?

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure which is why I'm just leaving a comment, but my guess is that arel is just faster compiling the first one. You may be able to get it even faster with something like `ids = current_user.activities.reverse_order.pluck(:person_id)`

Comment: `select{person_id}` is just refining the result, ignoring all other columns by `person_id`.

Comment: It's likely that the performance characteristic will flip if you have a lot more data.

Comment: I tried 1000 times `ids = current_user.activities.select(:person_id).map(&:person_id).reverse` vs `ids = current_user.activities.reverse_order.pluck(:person_id)` and found the former was still the minisculest bit faster (*about* 0.85 vs 0.88) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first query, you've chained .map and .reverse, while in the second query, you've used .order('id DESC') .select(person_id) which were unnecessary, if you added .reverse

Comment: Good point, I'd actually changed from ordering on `created_at` as they essentially did the same thing in this scenario, and forgot that reverse is doing this anyway. Good point

Comment: I optimised the query to `ids = current_user.activities.select(:person_id).map(&:person_id).reverse`, thanks for pointing this out